How can I determine the Channel ID of my Hikvision camera to use ISAPI?
I'm working on a project where I need to interact with a Hikvision camera model DS-TCG405-E through its ISAPI API. Using Postman, I have been able to retrieve information from the camera using the GET method and the /ISAPI/System/deviceInfo endpoint. However, when attempting to make other requests, such as /ISAPI/Traffic/channels//capabilities, where it is mentioned that the  in the request URI refers to the ID of the traffic channel, I have been unable to determine how to find this Channel ID.
I have consulted the Hikvision documentation and other available resources, but I have not found a clear way to obtain the Channel ID of the camera. Some online examples use 1 as the traffic channel ID, but it doesn't work for me. Is there any standard or convention for finding the Channel ID of a Hikvision camera using Postman or any other method?
I appreciate any guidance or advice on how I can correctly identify the Channel ID of my Hikvision camera in order to effectively use ISAPI from Postman.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Channel was always 1 for any single lens camera hikvision had.
There was difference when talked about streams then it was 101 for mainstream and 102 for substream.
It would be of great help if you posted response results, rather than implying it does not work. It might be entirely unrelated to ChannelID.
Also to mention, your traffic camera got different API than serie 7 LPR, hence if you use wrong documentation, it can be reason why it does not work.
